# After Installing Ubuntu, Stuck at Black Loading Screen

Tags: system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu from a bootable usb and written it to a drive.
What I have tried :

- I rebooted and selected the drive to boot from, even after  5 minutes long waiting it still show a blinking: "_"
- I rebooted several times
- I could use the usb but booting from it takes to long
- I've tried many options but nothing solved the problem
- I tried installing Ubuntu again and it detects that Ubuntu is on that drive

Should i just wait a long time? Because by experience i know that first boot always takes a lot of time.

Specs of my PC:

```
4gb ram
320gb wd 
1tb seagate barracuda drive.
```

Comment: Sorry to say you have a very slow computer and the bare minimum of RAM yes it will take a while to read the USB and install. You may want to research a lighter version like Lubuntu for this hardware. You may find it helpful to read this install tutor. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: well when i used the "taskmanager" i dont know how its called on ubuntu it said used 2gb
and another thing ubuntu just works fine when i am loaded on desktop (boot from usb) so i think the usb is the bottleneck sorry but this is not actualy helpfull

oh and it said the cd/dvd (its a usb) is faulty

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea what it is you used to see that you have 2 gig ram but you can not install Ubuntu in that.

Comment: ????? i dont get it anymore i think its just my garbage english

Comment: BTW is this a 32 bit only machine you are using?

Comment: no its a 64 bit processor sorry but i have to wait for more "profesional help"
i agree with a lighter version of linux but i am worried i could run less programs on it

Comment: No, anything you can run in the standard Ubuntu (with Gnome) you can run in any Ubuntu flavor wit other Desktop Environments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: You're saying it works ok in a live USB session but after installing & try to boot from the newly installed OS on the HDD you get a blinking _ - is that right? If so, I don't think the problem is the computer spec so long as the live session worked (that confirms your hardware is ok for Ubuntu); it could conceivably be the HDD as that's not used in a live USB session. I think you should edit your question with all the information you've given in comments & try to summarise exactly what problem you have as well as what fixes you tried. Also check the HDD in a live session.

Comment: well the hdd is fine i used it as a external drive before
and i written a test file to the drive but Karel has found something i need to test out so i hope it does work